# Сделать всплывающее сообщение в телеграм бот после нажатия на интерактивную кнопку с некой надписью

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def subcategory(message):
     
    if message.text == "Показать мой счёт":
        keyboard_subcategory = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=1)
        key1 = types.KeyboardButton('Далее')
        keyboard_subcategory.add(key1)  
        

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Нажми далее', reply_markup=keyboard_subcategory)
```

Comment: Добрый день. Не могли бы вы пожалуйста указать по точнее, что вам нужно?

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#answercallbackquery ?